# How I can integrate google maps AR navigation within the android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, augmented-reality

I want to integrate the google map AR navigation in the Android app programmatically.
Please help me if someone has any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Live View (AR navigation) is only available within the Google Maps app. If you want to present Live View within your app, you could [submit a Maps SDK for Android feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188870&template=788012) for adding Live View navigation.

You can also use [Google Maps Intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch-turn-by-turn-navigation) to open turn-by-turn navigation in the Google Maps app from your app, but there is no parameter to specify activating Live View so the user would have to locate and tap the Live View button once in Google Maps. If you would like to be able to launch Live View navigation in the Google Maps app from your app, you could [submit a Maps URLs feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=195646&template=861509) for adding a Live View mode parameter.

In the meantime, here's a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?product=googlemapsplatform&text=reality) teaching how to present nearby places in AR with ARcore alongside a map in your Android apps. You could use the skills taught in it and combine with the Directions API to construct your own AR navigation experience.